# Is it ever appropriate to put dependent variables in a model when they calculate the independent variable directly?

Tags: regression, prediction, model, multivariate-regression

Is it ever appropriate to fit a multivariable regression model with dependent variables that directly calculate the independent variable?
For example, I know that fitting a model to predict BMI by using height and weight and other variables in the model is a No-No since BMI=weight/height^2, however... what if I have a longitudinal data set where individuals have BMI measurements reported over time and I wanted to use a higher order term using height and weight (like time*height and time*weight and time*height*weight)? Is it still inappropriate to include the lower order term of height and weight in the model? Is it even appropriate to use the higher order terms that include height and weight?
I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: (1) Why wouldn't you want to include a variable that directly calculates the independent variable? This seems like the most desirable predictor, if only you can find such a predictor.

Comment: Because in this case it is a direct calculation. The weight/height^2 is how BMI was originally obtained so then trying to use weight and height to predict BMI isn't helpful or interesting.

Comment: On the contrary, using weight and height *in a suitable formula* would perfectly predict BMI.  If you didn't know how BMI was defined, this would be extremely informative, wouldn't it?  Neither mathematics nor statistics is concerned with the actual mechanism by which a response is related to potential explanatory variables (although a case could be made that causal theory has something to say about that).  It is hard to determine, then, what you really mean by "appropriate."